# Laravel 5.3 E-Mail Confirmation

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5.3, confirmation-email

I need to implement the functionality of confirmation of the email address of a user before making him able to login to my platform.

I have successfully implemented the sending of a confirmation code at registration and save a string "confirmation_code" and and a Boolean "confirmed" of whether a user is confirmed or not in the database.

The verification itself is also already implemented.

Now the only problem I have is the checking at login if the user is confirmed or not.
I read into the API of Laravel 5.3 but I could not figure out how to edit the login process in the way I like. I don't like changing too much of the original functionality of laravel, I just want to add a simple parameter to the authentication process during login. Cant be that hard can it?

Comment: accept my answer if it helped you or ask me anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I have found a solution for my problem.

I have now overriden the attemptLogin(Request $request) function with my personal preferences. Not a great deal if you know what you have to look for. I think it should be somehow clarified in the laravel docs because authenticate itself doesnt work at all.

However, here is my code if anyone is interested:

```
protected function attemptLogin(Request $request){
    return $this->guard()->attempt([
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => $request->password,
        'confirmed' => 1
    ], $request->has('remember'));
}
```

The code above is written in my LoginController.php file.

The only thing I now have to find out is how to detect why a login has failed so I can tell the user whether his/her email/password combination was wrong or their account is not activated yet.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Okay I tried to figure out how to detect the reason of why a user couldnt login to give the user better feedback on it, but I couldnt find anyway to do it.

Answer (score 1):

### **Laravel 5.3**

I know this question is a little old but anyone else looking for a answer that let you keep all of the funcionalities of Laravel's Auth easily. I believe I have one.

If you take a look at `Auth\AuthenticateUser` you'll notice that the method `login` uses the method `attemptLogin`, which gets the array of credentials from the method `credentials`.

Instead of overriding the whole login flow, just override the `credentials` method, that way you can simply set the email confirmation without losing error messages and such.

For a E-mail confirmation validation, in your case, you can do sommething like:

```
protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
        $credentials['confirmed'] = 1;
        return $credentials;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are using default LoginController
Override the authenticate method in the controller

```
public function authenticate()
{
    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'confirmed'=>1])) {
        // Authentication passed...
        return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
    }
}
```

add this to your controller

Comment: I couldnt find any AuthController anywhere. I also found your solution on the laravel docs but couldnt figure out how to implement this. Laravel 5.3s make:auth line created a LoginController and RegisterController for me (some more stuff but none relating to this topic). No AuthController to be found anywhere :(

Comment: then it is the LoginController add it inside of it

Comment: I tried it, but then all variables ($email, $password) would be unknown to the Controller since no data is passed to the authenticate() function.

Comment: you need to overrite

Comment: I will try it when I'm home. But I don't know if I am just stupid or how do I get the $email and $password variables? There is no Request passed to authenticate or anything else I could retrieve the needed data from. Will report back in a few hours when I am home

Comment: I tried adding the authenticate function to the LoginController right now. But as I expected it didnt work. I got several reasons for that.
1. There is no route going to the authenticate function (could try to call it login maybe)
2. I couldnt find any "authenticate" function in the framework, so I cant "override" it in anyway...since there is nothing to override.